# Has the \for loop command in Latex (pgffor package) been deprecated?

Tags: latex, texworks

I'm not able to get the \for command to work in TexWorks. \foreach works fine and \usepackage{pgffor} is declared.
Is it possible that \for has been deprecated?
I'm using TexLive / TexWorks 2021 edition.
Thanks in advance
afk

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgffor}
    \usetikzlibrary{math}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    %\foreach \n in {1,2,3,4} {$\n$}; This works."1234" displays as expected.
    \for \n in {1,2,3,4} {$\n$}; This reports "Undefined Control Sequence"
    \draw (0,0)--(10,0);   This works also.
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Can you include from which package you think the `\for` command came from? There are a couple of packages which provide it, but they are not for loops like the command from pgffor

Comment: My understanding is that the \for \foreach loop commands are coded in the pgffor package. I have pgffor declared and \foreach works but \for throws the error.

Comment: Why do you think pgffor would provide a `\for` macro?

Comment: An internet article in which (apparently) I misread \foreach as \for. It might have been a case of seeing what I wanted to see as opposed to what was actually there. My question was more of curiosity because \foreach works fine for my needs.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyzThe article I read was the tikz manual on page 28.
"2. The pgffor package defines a useful \foreach statement"
I had the document search set for "\for" and the "\for" of
\foreach was highlighted. I saw what I wanted to see ;-).

Answer (score 1):

This is the non-working code I submitted in the original post above.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgffor}
    \usetikzlibrary{math}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    %\foreach \n in {1,2,3,4} {$\n$}; This works."1234" displays as expected.
    \for \n in {1,2,3,4} {$\n$}; This reports "Undefined Control Sequence"
    \draw (0,0)--(10,0);   This works also.
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Below is the code corrected so it compiles and runs:

```
- usepackage{pgffor} is removed (See comment from samcarter)
- \tikzmath environment is invoked. 
- The correct loop command is actually "for"  NOT "\for"
- Note that the command argument of the for-loop requires nested braces.
- The advantage I found in "for" as opposed to "\foreach" is that variables
    can be modified with no extra code. This is shown in the second for-loop.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzmath{
for \n in {1,2,3,4}{{($n =\n $);};}; %  <----double braces here. . .
for \n in {2,3,4,5}{\m =log10(\n); {($Log \n =\m$;};}; % <---. . .and here.
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```